# Code Igniter displaying one record from database

Tags: javascript, database, codeigniter

How to display one record from a database? Basically I have a page that has a list of records and a link for each record that says vote. When I click on the vote link for a particular record, I want it to display only that record. How would I do this?

My code for displaying all the records in the view is:

```
<h2>List of all polls in this site:</h2>
<?php echo '<table>';?>
<h3>Title</h3>
<?php foreach ($polls as $polls_item): ?>

  <tr><td><a href="http://studweb.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/~njp63/365/polls/index.php/user">Vote</a>

<?php 

    echo $polls_item['title'] . "</td>";?>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo "<td>" .  $polls_item['text'] . "</td>";

?>
    </div>
   <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>


<?php endforeach ?>
<?php echo "</table>"; ?>
```

My model:

```
<?php
class Polls_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function get_polls($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('polls');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('polls', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function set_polls($title, $text)
    {

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post($title), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            //'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            //'slug' => $slug,
            //'text' => $this->input->post('text')

            'title' => $title,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $text
        );

        $this->db->insert('polls', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();

    }

    public function set_options($option, $pollid)
    {

        $values = $option;

        foreach ($values as $option){

            $options = array(
                'option_item' => $option,
                'poll_id' => $pollid
            );
            $this->db->insert('pollOption', $options);
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

// Debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_error', '1');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('polls_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['polls'] = $this->polls_model->get_polls();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('user/index', $data, TRUE);
        $data['title'] = 'Polls archive';
        $this->load->view('templates/master', $data);
    }

    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['polls_item'] = $this->polls_model->get_polls($slug);

        if (empty($data['polls_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->helper('html');
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('user/view', $data, TRUE);
        $data['title'] = $data['polls_item']['title'];
        $this->load->view('templates/master', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($polls as $polls_item): ?>

  <tr><td><a href="siteurl/controller/method/{$polls_item['id']}">Vote</a>

<?php 

    echo $polls_item['title'] . "</td>";?>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo "<td>" .  $polls_item['text'] . "</td>";

?>
    </div>
   <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>


<?php endforeach ?>
```

when you click on `Vote` the page will redirected to spacified url in `href`

**Controlller**

```
function method()
{
    $data   =   array();
    $data['record'] =   $this->db->get_where('tbl_name', array('id' => (int)$this->uri->segment(3)))->row_array();  

    //load the view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get only one record, use [WHERE clause](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) to specify which record do you want to get from the DB. And you can use GET parameters to pass something unique about the record, e.g. ID.

Comment: HOw would i do that using the links?

Comment: @NiraliPatel you can add a parameter just at the end of the link, so it looks like helloworld.php?id=123
and then retrieve using $_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your controller and model here? You need to have a method in the model that will query for that single result with the WHERE clause.

Comment: I have added my controller and model

Comment: Your model is missing a class definition.The constructor method won't do anything without that.

Comment: hey sorry.. seems like i forgot to paste it..:" <?php
class Polls_model extends CI_Model {  " Thats how i define it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass item_id to the vote link of each row in your view:

```
<? echo '<a href="http://studweb.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/~njp63/365/polls/index.php/user/view/"'.$polls_item['slug'].'">Vote</a>' ?>
```

Comment: can i use .$polls_item['id']. i have decided that i will not be using slugs. is this a better idea? and will it work? Thanks.

Comment: the best way to keep tracking your users/clients (and getting access to them) is to have unique identifier for each of them. If you have one, I would strongly suggest to use it. For instance, in this link switch `$polls_item['slug']` to `$polls_item['user_id']`. Therefore, in your `get_polls` function you will be retrieving data associated with this `user_id`